# I want to classify data by distance from centroids in python

Tags: svm, python, k-means

I'm making an image classifier that will tell if an image is a car or not, in Python.

here are my steps:

1. Get SIFT descriptors from about 200 images with cars on them.
2. On all those SIFT descriptors use k-means algorithm and find about 50 centroids.
3. Using those centroids and new images generate train data for SVM.

I want to find those k-mean centroids only once and then save them in file for reuse.

My problem is following:

I have 50 precalculated centroids. I have new image with SIFT descriptors. I want to find nearest centroids for each descriptor.

for example: centroid 1 is nearest to 5 descriptors, centroid 2 is nearest to 12 descriptors and so on. Then I will feed those data to SVM.

It is like kmeans.predict(), but i don't want to calculate k-means every time I add new image.

So is there any function in python where I give 50 points (centroids) in hyperspace, N points in same hyperspace and it will return me distribution of those N points according nearest centroids?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any negative examples? I do not see how you will use SVM to do this if you have only data for one class. You can also find the centroids and calculate the distance to the centroids, if none is below a threshold you can assume that it is not a car, (here you will need images of something that is not a car to find the threshold, i.e. something similar like a tractor or a truck to make it more robust).

Comment: i have also negative examples, and i think the class i looked for i spatial.KDTree, it can find nearest points